# How to set a class of my creation to be a key in a TreeMap (Java)

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

I created a class DateTime (which wraps GregorianCalendar). I also created a class Event.
I would like to create a collection of events from which I can retrieve an event by its date.
For instance:
event is of type Event;
date1 and date2 are of type DateTime and also date1.equals(date2);
'events' is my event collection.

```
event.put(date1, event)
```

will add 'event' to the collection so that I can retrieve it by

```
event.get(date2)
```

I think of using a TreeMap to implement this event collection because I might want to print all the events sorted by date.

So how to set DateTime to be a key of a TreeMap? What should I add to DateTime? and what else to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to have the `DateTime` implement `Comparable<DateTime>`, something along the lines of:

```
class DateTime implements Comparable<DateTime> {
  GregorianCalendar calendar;

  ...

  public int compareTo(DateTime other) {
    if (calendar.equals(other.calendar))
      return 0;
    else if (calendar.before(other.calendar))
      return -1;
    else
      return 1;
  }
}
```

The [Comparable interface](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) is documented [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways:

1. Make DateTime implement [Comparable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) < DateTime >. Define the compareTo() method.
2. Define a class (may be anonymous) that implements [Comparator](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) < DateTime >. Define its compare() method as required. Pass an instance of that class into the constructor of your TreeMap.